# two td tag don't slide side by side

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

Hello I develop a app where td appear and disapear side by side.

```js
lastInsertTd = 0;
function newSlidingTd() {
  tr = jQuery('#myline');
  var lastTd = jQuery('#myline').children().last();

    td = jQuery("<td></td>")
      .attr('id', 'slidingTd' + lastInsertTd+1)
      .attr('style', 'display:none;vertical-align:top;width:100%');
    tr.append(td);
    tdSuivant = jQuery('#slidingTd' + lastInsertTd+1);
    tdActuel = jQuery('#slidingTd' + lastInsertTd);

  /*animation*/
    tdActuel.toggle('slide', {
      direction: 'left'
    }, 500);
    tdSuivant.toggle('slide', {
      direction: 'right'
    }, 500);
lastInsertTd = lastInsertTd+1;
}
```

```css
table {
  width:100px
}
td {
  border: black solid 1px;
  width:100%
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr id="myline">
    <td id='slidingTd0' onclick="newSlidingTd()">
      1
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

But when I call my event, my new td doesn't slide from the right but a little bit lower. How can I go through this "bug"? (this also happen when I create div inside td)

Comment: Problem is, that your TD tag is 100% width of table.

Comment: Also `td` and other table elements don't work well with animations.

Comment: Remove the width 100% css from td as Autista_z has said and it should work.

Comment: I delete all my width 100% and that doesn't work...

Answer (score 0):

if it's slightly lower, then most likely it's some issue with displaying whitespaces.

Try setting `line-height: 0;` in the parent element (`tr` I'd guess), or remove the whitespace between `< /td >< td >`